# Use of caret symbol (^) in Ruby

Tags: ruby, operators, caret

```
1 ^ 1
# => 0

1 ^ 2
# => 3

5 ^ 6
# => 3
```

These are the results I am getting. Can, please, somebody explain how `^` works?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It's a [bitwise XOR operator.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR)

For each bit in the binary representation of the operands, a bitwise XOR will get a 1 bit if one of the corresponding bits in the operands is 1, but not both, otherwise the XOR will get a 0 bit. Here's an example:

```
5     = 101
6     = 110
5 ^ 6 = 011 = 3
```

Comment: I wasn't actually aware that Ruby has binary literals, since I'm not a Ruby dev:)

Comment: Thanks, helped me to decrypt this silliness I found in someone's code: `if (blocks[blockname] ^ invertBlock) or consts['Type'] == blockname`

Comment: Can think of it as this as an equivalent in logic operations: `(a || b) && !(a && b)`

Comment: xor: one or the other, not both