# What does :^ in reduce method mean?

Tags: ruby, reduce

I was doing a challenge on Code Wars where I was given an array "numbers" with several (sometimes repeating) integers and I had to return one unique integer. I passed the challenge but when I looked at all the previously submitted solutions, I noticed this reduce method:

```
def stray (numbers)
  numbers.reduce(&:^)
end
```

I know what reduce method generally does but I haven't been able to find what the symbol ^ means. Could anyone please let me know its purpose?

Comment: Hint: [`Integer#^`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Integer.html#method-i-5E) is a bitwise exclusive or. And [`Enumerable#reduce`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) combines all elements of the array by applying that operation.

Comment: Non-hint: ...and `numbers.reduce(&:^)` is shorthand for `numbers.reduce { |result, result ^ n }`. Incidentally, in this case one can simplify to: `numbers.reduce(:^)`. The latter uses the second form of [Enumerable#reduce](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) (aka `inject`).

Comment: Do you know what `foo(&:bar)` means? Do you know what `:bar` means in that snippet. Then, logically, what does `:^` mean in the snippet `reduce(&:^)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reduce method is used on arrays to combine all elements of that array into a single item.

The reduce method accepts a starting value and a block of code.

What you are using is a shorthand version of reduce which means the following:

`numbers.reduce(&:^)`

The & character will attempt to call the method on the argument itself when it is used as a last argument of a method call or definition. The ^ character signifies the bitwise [XOR operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163093/use-of-caret-symbol-in-ruby).

Inject is also an alias for reduce in Ruby.

You can read more [here](https://medium.com/whynotio/shorthand-syntax-for-each-map-reduce-more-a790ba12edc9).